# Convert Date to Natural Language Using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, web, time, momentjs

Currently, I am developing a website where input is required to take multiple dates that could be sequential, or random dates.

After the dates have been selected using a datepicker, I want to display them in natural language.

For example:

- January 4th - 8th
- Tomorrow
- This weekend

Is there a way to do this in [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/)? I can not seem to figure it out. If not, are there any other libraries available that I can use?

I found [SugarJS](http://sugarjs.com/dates), which does the opposite of what I need.

**Edit:**

I am looking for something that can accept a bunch of random dates, and present them in a human readable way. MomentJS is great for single dates, but I have not found a way to create a moment with multiple dates (that can be in any order) and have it presented in a nice way.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest referring to the MomentJS documentation that you linked to. At least one of those cases is likely handled with their `humanize` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need time, relative to current, consider using [fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use add() to refer a date in the future

future = moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();